# Will an HDMI to DP adapter work for Daisy Chaining?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I am looking to set up dual monitors to my work pc. The GPU of the computer is on the lower end and only has a single HDMI port and a VGA port. The two monitors I have do not have any VGA ports so the only functional port I have access to is the single HDMI.

I had an idea to get an HDMI -> DP cable to run from the tower into the first monitor and then daisy chain the second monitor to the first. Will this setup work as intended?

(The two monitors are Dell)

Comment: No.  Just get a VGA to HDMI converter.  Or get a cheap graphics card

Comment: I believe that daisy chaining monitors (DP MST) requires that all the equipment including the video card supports DP1.2. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000128707/how-to-daisy-chain-multiple-monitors-using-displayport-multi-stream-transport-mst#:~:text=DisplayPort%20Multi%2DStream%20Transport%20allows,your%20computer%20or%20docking%20station.

Comment: Just a quick note: a *DisplayPort to HDMI cable* is not reversible and often does not contain any converter. It relies on the Dual-Mode DisplayPort feature. Be careful not to buy stuff you cannot use.

Comment: @RohitGupta I have tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @DanielB that is what I was worried about. I have found many DP to HDMI cables but they will not work as intended. I did manage to find a converted that specifically mentions that it converts HDMI to DP but it is more money than I am prepared to spend on something that might not even work towards my goal

Comment: @DanielCharles - If a VGA to HDMI cable did not work, then perhaps you have to consider that your GPU is not upto the task.  Cheap graphics cards are not that expensive.  If it's for work, then surely your work will fork out the money.